# Configure Query Log for Cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I need to log timestamp, user id, and SQL code for every query executed against my database. On a standalone instance this could be done easily with the log_statement = true parameter. But it appears this is not supported in Cloud SQL, and Stackdriver logging doesn't seem to go this granular.

Is there another mechanism that can be used to log user queries?

Comment: Hey @michael-ames, where you able to figure this out? I have a similar situation (using Postgres). Would appreciate help or pointing in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using that Cloud SQL instance as a back-end for a webapp, you can use StackDriver logging libraries and write the logs at the points in your apps where Db access occurs.

In maven, you will need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.26.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a small usage example:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Quickstart {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Quickstart.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Logging INFO with java.util.logging");
    logger.severe("Logging ERROR with java.util.logging");
  }
}
```

Read [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java) on this. Hope it helps